# Why runs the component 2 times with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

On the screen I get : Hello { "name" : "Jack" }

In console I get:

1. App rendering
2. useFetch useEffect
3. App rendering

Because what I have seen in the console , I think App.js must have ran 2 times and useFetch must have ran 1 time .

I think this is behind :

1. App.js calls useFetch and writes on console that App rendering . App.js does NOT wait useFetch to complete, so Hello undefined is on the screen . BUT we don't see undefined on the screen , because it is so fast and it goes away -> because of 2. step :
2. While App.js writes on console and displays undefined on screen , useFetch is running . When useFetch completes its running it gives back the correct object ( Jack )
3. App.js component runs again and writes again on console and displays the correct object ( Hello Jack )

But if this is true , then why runs App.js 2 times ?

Somebody said that my theory about this is false and useFetch gives back 2 times value . First it gives back null as object and second time the correct value , which is from fetch . So he said that useFetch does not wait fetch function to complete , so it gives back first time null and when fetch function completes then it gives back Jack .
But if he has right , then why is that ? Why does not wait useFetch to complete its functions to complete ?

Can somebody write step by step whats happening behind ?

**App.js :**

```
import { useFetch } from './useFetch';

function App() {
    const { data } = useFetch({ url : "jack.json" })
    console.log('App rendering')
    return (
        <div className="App">
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div> )
}

export default App;
```

**useFetch.js :**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useFetch = (options) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useFetch useEffect");
        fetch(options.url)
            .then( response => response.json())
            .then( json  => setData(json))
    }, [])

    return { data }
}
```

My Question inspired this :
https://youtu.be/dH6i3GurZW8?t=316

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thinking is correct.

> But if this is true , then why runs App.js 2 times ?

Because `App` is a react component and like all other react components it will re-render whenever its data dependencies change. In your case, `App` will re-render whenever the value of `data` changes.

Your custom `useFetch` hook uses the `useEffect` hook to fetch data. Effects in React are performed after react components have rendered. That's why the console logs the first "App rendering". Once the `useFetch` hook calls `setData`, the value of `data` is updated which triggers the second re-render of `App`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step-by-step of what's happening:

```
function App() {
    const { data } = useFetch({ url : "jack.json" })
    console.log('App rendering')
    return (
        <div className="App">
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div> )
}
```

Before I begin, it may help to also understand how the react [component lifecycle](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) works:

[image]

---

From the start, it's just like calling a regular function...

If you refer to the diagram above, we are at the stage called **`render`**, because the body of a functional component is the equivalent of the render function in class components.

### First, `useFetch` is called

```
const { data } = useFetch({ url : "jack.json" });
```

#### *Inside `useFetch`*

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

*At this point, `data` is `null`*

##### *Next `useEffect` is called*

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useFetch useEffect");
    fetch(options.url)
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then( json  => setData(json))
}, []);
```

*`useEffect`* creates an effect watcher. This is basically a function which is invoked every time one of its dependencies changes. However, it is not invoked until ***after*** the first time the component renders.

If you refer to the diagram above, the watcher will only be invoked for the first time at the point called **`componentDidMount`**.

### Back inside `App`:

[image]
*(image reposted to avoid scrolling)*

```
console.log('App rendering')
```

*We get a nice console.log output...*

```
return (
        <div className="App">
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
);
```

Here we return control back to react, and it will now attempt to take our html and mount it inside the dom.

***Note** that `data` is still null*. Every other component react encounters will go through the same process described above.

So far, the steps leading up to this point can be summarized as **`Mounting`** (*See the diagram above*), and we have now reached the **componentDidMount** stage.

### `componentDidMount`

React will now invoke our effect.

***Note**: If you had more than one effect, react will invoke **all** of them, and none will be skipped for this first round of effectual work that react does. Also they will all be invoked in the same order you declared them in.*

#### *useEffect watcher invoked*

```
console.log("useFetch useEffect");
```

*Another nice printout to console.log*

```
fetch(options.url)
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then( json  => setData(json))
```

[`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is invoked, but since we are not allowed to wait for promises inside effects, the fetch just runs.

***Note**: If your effect returns any function, react saves it to run it the next time an update/unmount occurs.*

---

At this point, we just kinda idle until something interesting hap...oh wait `fetch` is done.

### State Updates (`setData(...)`)

[image]
*(image reposted to avoid scrolling)*

```
.then( json  => setData(json))
```

`setData` will update the state of the component. If you refer to the diagram above once again, you'll see that when a state update occurs, the next step is to render.

Therefore, react will once again repeat the same steps as above, but it does not re-create the `useEffect`, or the `useState` again, because it has stored them from the previous render.

***Sidenote**: This is also how react is able to detect when you are calling a hook (`useEffect`, `useState`, etc) conditionally. If react detects a new hook after the first render is finished, it will warn you of this*

#### *App is rendered again*

```
console.log('App rendering')
```

Next...

```
return (
        <div className="App">
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
);
```

And we once again return the html content of our component (this time `data` is now whatever was sent to `setData`).

#### Updating

As you can tell, we are now in the `Updating` Phase. From now on, react will simply wait for props/state updates, and runs any effects that depend on them in the `componentDidUpdate` stage of the lifecycle

***Sidenote**: Your `useEffect` should depend on `options.url` so that it is re-run when the url changes*

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useFetch useEffect");
    fetch(options.url)
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then( json  => setData(json))
}, [options?.url]);
```

### Unmounting

If by some bad luck, your component is unmounted either by the parent, or by some strange magic, your component will be moved into the `Unmounting` phase. Once again, refer to the diagram above

In this phase, none of the effects are run. Instead, any functions returned by your "effect watcher", will be invoked to do cleanup.

***Note**: All the cleanup functions will be run in the order they were encountered (typically top-down)*